# What does 'get away without' mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

From a discussion of approaches to grading in college, found at [Voice of America News](https://learningenglish.voanews.com/amp/you-will-not-get-grades-at-these-colleges/3997985.html):

> Rios said just because students are not getting letter grades does not mean students can **get away without** working hard. The detailed reviews by teachers mean they need to understand what is being taught, she said.

Comment: What does it seem like it means, from context?

Answer (score 1):

I think the cited usage is a bit of a mash-up. The standard idiomatic expression expression here is...

> [**get away with (something)**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/get-away-with-sth) *- to succeed in avoiding punishment for something*

To remain idiomatic, it should be...

> *...does not mean students can get away with **not working hard***.